# iOS SideMenu v3.1.4 calls lifecycle methods out of order

Tags: ios, swift

I was successfully using SideMenu 2.3.4 in my app, then upgraded to v3.1.4. I made the few mods required to adjust to API changes, then ran my app - it crashed after the following UI actions:

1. Open the menu by tapping on the nav bar button
2. Tap on item that loads another view (the menu closes, the new view appears)
3. Tap on the nav bar button to open the menu again

The menu didn't open in response to that last tap before the app crashed. Under the debugger, I saw that after 2, viewDidLoad then viewWillAppear were called for that new view. After 3, viewWillDisappear, viewDidDisappear and viewWillAppear of that same view were called, all without any change in the display.

The crash happened in viewWillAppear because my code counts on viewDidLoad being the first thing that is called after viewDidDisappear. AFAIK, it is legitimate to count on that, since viewDidDisappear is supposed to mean that the view was closed and thus has to be reloaded and viewDidLoad called before any other life-cycle method can be called, i.e., viewWillAppear should not have been called before viewDidLoad.

Am I misunderstanding the iOS view life-cycle? Is this a bug in SideMenu 3.1.4?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: you may consider adding some code in a `dealloc` method to determine if your view controller is getting removed from memory. If it is still in memory then `viewDidLoad` will not get called again since the view is "loaded" just not on the screen anymore. (Swift Dealloc is documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closer reading of the docs and articles on the net show that I did misunderstand the life-cycle methods.

There is no opposite of viewDidLoad (e.g., viewDidUnload), but in viewDidDisappear one can do this:

```
if (isBeingDismissed || isMovingFromParentViewController) {
    // Do something - viewWillAppear will NOT be called before viewDidLoad.
}
```

That eliminates the crash I was seeing.

Mark